# Substitute non-matching-pattern strings in every line of a file

Tags: awk, sed

From following file:

```
 1  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k' 
 2  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736
 3  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409
 4  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'  
 5  WAIT #1404991: nam='redo log sync' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677
 6  WAIT #1404991: nam='redo log sync' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432
 7  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
 8  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
 9  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
10  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849
11  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b' 
12  WAIT #1404991: nam='PGA memory operation' ela= 603 tim=4217919229470
13  WAIT #1404991: nam='PGA memory operation' ela= 1 tim=4217919229647
14  WAIT #1404991: nam='PGA memory operation' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185
```

I want to display everything, but for strings inside a line non-matching `SQL*Net message` between `nam='` and `' ela=`, I want these strings to be replaced with `Other DB operation` (and keep `nam='` and `' ela=` before and after these strings):

```
 1  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k' 
 2  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736
 3  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409
 4  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b' 
 5  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677
 6  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432
 7  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036' 
 8  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
 9  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
10  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849
11  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'  
12  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 603 tim=4217919229470
13  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 1 tim=4217919229647
14  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185
```

Is there a sed or awk command that'll allow me to do that easily?

Comment: The answers seem to solve your problem. Please mind https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Please try this awk solution, tested with GNU Awk:

```
awk '/redo/{sub(/redo log sync/, "Other DB operation")}1' Input_file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '                                      # Start program
/redo/{                                    # On lines matching the regex `redo`
sub(/redo log sync/, "Other DB operation") # replace `redo log sync` with `Other DB Operation`
}1                                         # print
' Input_file                               # Input file goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'next if /nam=.SQL[*]Net message. ela=/; s/(nam=)\S.*\s+(ela=)/${1}'\''Other DB operation'\'' ${2}/' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

Parenthesis around `(nam=)` and `(ela=)` capture these patterns into variables `$1` and `$2`.
`.` is any character.
`.*` is any character, repeated 0 or more times.
`\S` is a non-whitespace character.
`\s` is a whitespace character.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$0!~/SQL\*Net/{gsub(/nam=.*ela/, "nam='\''Other DB operation'\''",$0)} 1' input_file.txt
```

gives

```
 1  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k' 
 2  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736
 3  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409
 4  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'  
 5  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation'= 1 tim=4217919225677
 6  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation'= 736 tim=4217919226432
 7  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
 8  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
 9  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
10  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849
11  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b' 
12  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation'= 603 tim=4217919229470
13  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation'= 1 tim=4217919229647
14  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation'= 521 tim=4217919230185
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -ri '/Net message/!{/PARSING/!s/(^.*'"'"')(.*)('"'"'.*)/\1Other DB operation\3/}' file
```

Using sed. For all lines not containing "Net message" (!) and then not containing "PARSE", split the line into 3 sections and substitute the line for the first section followed by "Other DB Operation" and the third section.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match:

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/(.*nam=\047)([^\047]*)(\047 ela.*)/,a) && (a[2] != "SQL*Net message") {
        $0 = a[1] "Other DB operation" a[3]
    }
1' file
 1  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k'
 2  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736
 3  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409
 4  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'
 5  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677
 6  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432
 7  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
 8  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
 9  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
10  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849
11  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'
12  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 603 tim=4217919229470
13  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 1 tim=4217919229647
14  WAIT #1404991: nam='Other DB operation' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185
```

Note that the above is doing string operations and so treats the characters in the string you want to find and the one you replace it with as literal so you don't need to escape regexp metachars (e.g. `.` or `*`) or backreferences (e.g. `&` or `\<number>`) in them.